# YAML Syntax Validator Script

Tags: syntax, yaml

I've been tasked with creating and editing quite a few YAML files, but rather than using an online syntax validator, I'm looking to run it through a script.  Are there any available scripts that will test YAML Syntax?  I found one through Perl that used perl::xs, but it wasn't particularly portable.

Comment: There are several [modules](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML) available for parsing YAML. They should all be able to give you some sort of feedback if your input contains syntactic errors.

Comment: Could you clarify "portable"?  YAML::XS will work on just about any operating system.  Do you mean something which can be shipped from machine to machine without recompiling?

Answer (score 2):

You should try [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/YAML-0.84/lib/YAML.pm) on CPAN, which is pure perl without dependencies, so it's portable. You can even just download it and put them with your validator script without installation.

Here is a example validator script:

```perl
use YAML qw(LoadFile);
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = LoadFile($ARGV[0]);
print Dumper($data);
```

If any error occurred, the error message will tell you where's the problem:

```
YAML Error: Expected separator '---'
   Code: YAML_PARSE_ERR_NO_SEPARATOR
   Line: 1
   Document: 2
 at /Users/alec/perl5/perlbrew/perls/p5161t/lib/site_perl/5.16.1/YAML/Loader.pm line 81.
```

Comment: YAML.pm is a poor YAML implementation [by its own admission](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML#NOTE).  You can use [YAML::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML::Any) to pick the best available YAML implementation installed.

Comment: Agree. In fact I use YAML::XS in most of my projects. But since @securitygate mentioned his dislike of XS, I guess he wants a script level solution.

Comment: YAML::Any is a script level solution.  It will pick the best installed version for you.  If YAML::XS is available, it will use that.  If its not, it'll use YAML.pm.